# Generate example (Iris) dataset with python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to try out some manipulation with python, and having worked with [R](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(langage)) there is very handy feature that enables to get an example dataset like this

```
> v <- iris
> v
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa
6            5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     setosa
7            4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3     setosa
8            5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa
9            4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2     setosa
```

Is it possible with numpy to generate some example dataset to play around ?

Comment: The equivalent would be [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org)'s [datasets](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/datasets/index.html). E.g. [iris](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_iris.html#sklearn.datasets.load_iris).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scikit learn actually provides that dataset (as mentioned by @sascha). You can use [`load_iris()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_iris.html):

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
data = load_iris()
```

You can make it into a dataframe with pandas to even better replicate R:

```
import pandas as pd
species = [data['target_names'][x] for x in data['target']]
pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([data['data'], species]),
    columns=data['feature_names'] + ['species']
)
```